Создание ордера на субаккаунте ByBIT (копитрейдер)
На ByBIT создал акк, отладил открытие ордеров и теперь хочу открывать ордера в режиме копитрейдера. Создал субаккаунт, прошел проверку на мастер-трейдер, получил API. При попытке создать ордер получаю ошибку: position idx not match position mode (ErrCode: 10001) (ErrTime: 07:27:13). Request → POST https://api.bybit.com/v5/order/create: {"category": "linear", "symbol": "RNDRUSDT", "orderType": "Market", "side": "Sell", "qty": "4.5"}
Что я делаю не так?

Разобрался. Не изменил режим хеджирования на бирже.
